# NameError at /api/1 name 'Employee' is not defined

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, view, nameerror

Internal Server Error: /api/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\python practice\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "E:\python practice\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "E:\python django\New folder (2)\gs10\api\views.py", line 48, in employeeDetailview
employee = Employees.objects.get(pk=pk)
File "E:\python practice\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "E:\python practice\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 439, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
api.models.Employees.DoesNotExist: Employees matching query does not exist.

```
def employeeDetailview(request,pk):
    
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=pk)
    print(employee)
    
    return JsonResponse('Employee'+ str(pk),safe=False)
```

Comment: can you please add further detail so other understand your problem and don't post whole error please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Get Object with `id` instead of `pk`

```
try:
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(employee)

    return JsonResponse({"employee_id":str(pk),employee_name:employee.name},safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({"error":str(e)},safe=False)
```